# Alternating values depending on day of the week

Tags: php

I am trying to change the variable for each day of the week and insert it into a table in sql, but I am having trouble getting the correct value when I cycle trough an array of 7 which represents the seven days of the week.
I don't think I am doing this correctly.

```
$daysOfWeek = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

foreach($daysOfWeek as $day){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblUser (iUserID, iLocID, iDay, iFirstTime, iLastTime)
                        VALUES (:user, :location, :day, :first, :last)"; 

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam (':user', $_SESSION['userID']);
    $stmt->bindParam (':location', $_SESSION['locationID']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':day', $day);
    if($day[0]){
        $stmt->bindParam(':first', $decFD->sunEarliest);
        $stmt->bindParam(':last', $decFD->sunLatest);
        echo $day;
    }elseif ($day[1]){
        $stmt->bindParam(':first', $decFD->monEarliest);
        $stmt->bindParam(':last', $decFD->monLatest);
        echo $day;
...continuing until I reach $day[6]
```

Essentially I am entering 7 records that represents each day f the week but all other information remains the same..anyone know how I can accomplish this? In other words when we look at the db we should see

```
  iUser  iLocID  iDay  iFirstTime  iLastTime

    1      151     1      2          8
    1      151     2      3          8
    1      151     3      2          8
    1      151     4      3          8
    1      151     5      2          8
    1      151     6      2          8
    1      151     7      2          8
```

iFirstTime would be a range of times from  1-10 same for iLastTime
however i seem to be getting whatever day 1 is, I am sure it is because of the way I am looping through the array.

Comment: `$day` is a number, what do you think `$day[0]` is trying to do?

Comment: Use `if ($day ==1) { ....} elseif ($day==2){ ...}` Remember the `foreach` breaks the array into its component parts, in this case `1,2,3,....

Answer (score 1):

You run into trouble here:

```
if($day[0]){
     $stmt->bindParam(':first', $decFD->sunEarliest);
     $stmt->bindParam(':last', $decFD->sunLatest);
     echo $day;

 }elseif ($day[1]){
     $stmt->bindParam(':first', $decFD->monEarliest);
     $stmt->bindParam(':last', $decFD->monLatest);
     echo $day;
     ...continuing until I reach $day[6]
```

Instead of checking the $day variable, you passing the individual characters of the var into the if statement, (i.e. `$day[0]` = first char, `$day[1]` = second, etc.). Instead you want this:

```
if($day === 1){
     $stmt->bindParam(':first', $decFD->sunEarliest);
     $stmt->bindParam(':last', $decFD->sunLatest);
     echo $day;

 }elseif ($day === 2){
     $stmt->bindParam(':first', $decFD->monEarliest);
     $stmt->bindParam(':last', $decFD->monLatest);
     echo $day;
     ...continuing until I reach $day === 7
```

Comment: i'll give that a go, but why does it work differently when working with the indexes of the array instead of the values? Like in my case where I was using the indexes I was only getting the time taken in for sunEarliest and that was auto populating the rest

Comment: @Cookies `$day` isn't an array, it's an integer, so you were grabbing individual character indexes from it, e.g. $day[0] gets the 1st character of `1`, which is `1`. Also, you weren't comparing anything with an equals operator, so the if statements were interpreting it as boolean.